# Creating twitter app under the new 2.0 projects

Tags: twitterapi-python

Unexpectedly, I got an email today saying that my (simple and long-lived) twitter app violated terms and conditions. This is must be due to the 2.0 initiative. We can skip the discussion about the zero direct notifications on the changes to terms and services and the fact that the activity of my app (posting once or twice per day) still conforms to the new policy. My question is about how to create an app. I created the project, I have one app that is suspended and I see no way to create a new app to add into the new project. Do I have to delete the old (standalone & suspended) app to be able to even see an option to create a new app?

Pre 2.0 app suspended.
Created a Twitter 2.0 project.
Expected an option to create an app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to projects from the dashboard and click on manage and remove the desired app from the list.
You can create another app and then use it with the new Twitter API.

Comment: Right, this is what I suspected but the twitter docs don't seem to explain this at all. I opened a support case with twitter (I bet they have thousands open since this change) and I didn't want to delete an app that I had an open support case over! But I think they will never reply. If I designed this, I would let users create and explore multiple apps and the project itself should have the usage limits enforced, not the app. But anyway, thanks again. I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation. If I'm ever reputable enough, I'll come back here :)

Comment: Thats fine :)
Right, they also haven't included much documentation for the new Twitter API V2, I will include a link below so that you can check their examples, since you will have to migrate to the new API. 
https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code